# Configuring server for HTML5 video

Tags: windows, html5-video

I'm trying to put HTML 5 video on my site, and for some reason it won't work.

I put the exact same folder on two different servers.  On one it works, on the other it doesn't.

Here's the one where it works:  http://www.unitedsytes.com/vid/vid.php

Here's the one where it doesn't work: http://www.promilitarybusinessnetwork.com/vid/vid.php

I've added phpinfo so you can see the configuration of the server, and hopefully see what exactly is the difference that makes it work on one and not on the other.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that ogv and mp4 are set up in the IIS mime types?

When IIS gets a request for a file type which is NOT in the mime types list, it will not serve it.